# Dc.js - Row Chart with dynamic height

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I created a row chart by Dc.js. I've got dynamic data, So i've got multiple kind  of data every time. Now, my problem is that my row chart's height is statica and **Svg is Compressed** and unclear:

```
rowChart = dc.rowChart('#rowChart');

rowChart 
 .width(300)
 .height(300)
 .margins({ top: 20, left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20 })
 .group(barChartDimensionGroup)
 .dimension(barChartDimension)
 ...
```

And i've got a error:

> Error: Invalid negative value for  attribute
>   height="-4.894322420223788"

Comment: @Gordon, plaese see this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution through @gordon:

```
 rowChart = dc.rowChart('#rowChart');
 var heightRowChart=0;
 heightRowChart = rowChartDimensionGroup.all().length;

 tmpRowChart /* dc.rowChart('#day-of-week-chart', 'chartGroup') */
 .width(300)
 .height(heightRowChart*30)
 ...
```

Comment: I guess this must be a row chart. Looks good! An easier way to get the number of items might be `barChartDimensionGroup.all().length`

Comment: Yes, that's RowChart Mr.@Gordon. That work:
 var heightRowChart = rowChartDimensionGroup.all().length;

Thanks a lot.